# How to create Outlook templates(like .oft or .msg) for MAC outlook

Tags: windows, macos, outlook, html-email, email-client

Can any body please advise how to create Outlook templates(like .oft or .msg) for MAC outlook by making use of Windows outlook. Is it doable? Do we need to do in any other format?  or at-least how to do reusable outlook templates on Mac for multiple Mac users like the way we do for Windows Outlook which they can directly open and use. I tried searching but didn't get exact answers.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook for Mac doesn't offer this functionality.

The closest you can get is by opening the HTML file in Word and doing a mail merge to Outlook. But this is very bad practice and highly not advisable.

Here is the official Q&A: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-create-email-templates-in-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-6339b60e-2e5a-4aed-a9e6-2e7b5d7eb5a0

Answer (score 0):

When you have an Office 365 Subscription and use Insider Fast updates on your OutLook for Mac this new Email Template feature is now available. [See this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/outlookformac/2017/04/12/insider-fast-email-template-is-now-available/).